# How to make .exe file from html5 css application?

Tags: javascript, windows, html5

I would like to make windows desktop application using HTML5, JavaScript and CSS. I am trying

- [tidesdk](http://www.tidesdk.org)
- [XULRunner](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/XULRunner)
- [appjs](http://appjs.org)

I read the documentations of these technologies. But I didn't see how to export the application as a .exe package. I want to write an application in HTML and JavaScript and export to an exe file. How can I do that?

Comment: There's also node-webkit, which can make a standalone exe for Windows, Linux, and Mac.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're almost there, you'll just have to dig into the documentation a bit deeper. ;-)

For example, Steps 5 and 6 in the [tidesdk Getting Started Guide](http://tidesdk.multipart.net/docs/user-dev/generated/#!/guide/getting_started) create the EXE file and the deployment package.